# Use Expect script with Expect/send

Tags: linux, expect

I want to get the value from the SQL command below. But I've got an error message every time.

The Expect code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 60

spawn ssh -i id_rsa user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
sleep 10
send -- "sudo su\r"
sleep 10
expect '[sudo] password for user: '
send -- "secret\r"
sleep 2
send "mysql -u root\r"
sleep 2
send -- "use nextcloud;\r"
sleep 2
send -- "SELECT * FROM oc_accounts;\r"
```

Error message:

```
spawn ssh -i id_rsa user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
invalid command name "sudo"
    while executing
"sudo"
    invoked from within
"expect '[sudo] password for user: ' "
    (file "./test.sh" line 8)
```

Comment: Expect uses the [Tcl language](http://www.tcl.tk/) which has different syntax from shell. If you are more comfortable with shell syntax you can use [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect).

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes have no special meaning in Expect. Expect is an extension of Tcl, where [braces are the non-interpolating quoting mechanism](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M10).

You get the "invalid command name" error because square brackets are the Tcl command substitution syntax.

You want

```
expect {[sudo] password for user: }
```

---

Instead of `sleep`, with idiomatic Expect you should `expect` some pattern: your remote shell's prompt, the MySQL prompt, etc.

---

@pynexj has a good point. Try

```
expect -exact {[sudo] password for user:}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it still doesn't work.
is this correct?
expect {"[sudo] password for user: "}
send -- "password"
it also doesn't work without quotation marks. have I forgotten something?
ive got no error but the cli expect a password

Comment: You don't want the inner quotes -- the braces already are the quoting you need.. Perhaps the actual sudo prompt does not include a space after the colon. Run your code with `expect -d script.exp` to see exactly why the patterns don't match.

Comment: `expect {[sudo] password for user: }` would not work. by default the pattern is GLOB style so the `[sudo]` part can only match `s`, `u`, `d` or `o`.